# YCSB cleanup phase

Tags: mysql, mongodb, ycsb, database

```
[CLEANUP], Operations, 1
[CLEANUP], AverageLatency(us), 627.0
[CLEANUP], MinLatency(us), 627
[CLEANUP], MaxLatency(us), 627
[CLEANUP], 95thPercentileLatency(ms), 0
[CLEANUP], 99thPercentileLatency(ms), 0
[CLEANUP], 0, 1
[CLEANUP], 1, 0
[CLEANUP], 2, 0
[CLEANUP], 3, 0
[CLEANUP], 4, 0
```

Taken from YCSB output, what is a database `cleanup` operation? I am trying to understand why MySQL takes so much longer during this phase than a MongoDB system.

Answer (score 0):

The `cleanup` operation is needed to shut down the thread(s) which was providing the workload to the db. So, if you set the parameter `-thread n`, you will see exactly `n` `cleanup` operations at the end of the benchmark!